# error while Live Search using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Unable to get the results from database..!
This is my Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Live Search</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function findName(str)
        {
            $.POST("names.php",{partialName:str},function(data));
            $("#result").innerHtml=data;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        Enter The Name: <input type="text" onkeypress="findName(this.value)">
        <br>
        <div id="result">

        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

This is names.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");

$name=$_POST['partialName'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT fname FROM name where fname LIKE '%$name';")or die(mysql_error());

while($list=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<div>".$result['fname']."</div>";
}
```

?>

And the error i am getiing while inspecting the element is:
Uncaught ReferenceError: findName is not definedonkeypress @ (index):16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit Your Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findName(str)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "names.php",
        data: {
        partialName: str
    },
    success: function(data){
            $("#result").innerHtml=data;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this line `$.POST("names.php",{partialName:str},function(data));` will throw an error (check console)

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'
>
> ReferenceError: findName is not defined

check [jQuery POST](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to see it

Here's a quick fix (added name to input too):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function findName(str)
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "names.php",
        data: {
        partialName: str
        },
        success: function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="str" onkeypress="findName(this.value)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So it should work ..

```
function findName(str){
      $.post("names.php",{partialName:str},function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.POST is not a functionfindName @ (index):7onkeypress @ (index):16

Comment: The function is correct, even though now I can not test it.